# Question about Jannah

Tags: sunnah, jannah

I have only a few questions so please if you have an answer respond :

If I get to Jannah Isha’Allah May Allah make us upon those people, can I ask to :

1. Have an « identical » of any women that was here in dunya ?
2. Have a mini dunya in which I can relive my life with a few differences, you know like « new party » in video game ?

Barrak’Allah-u fikoum for taking the time of reading my questions. Once again May Allah grant Allah of the Moumineen Jannah tul Firdaws

Comment: Do you think you'd have the same whishes once in Jannah?

Comment: This question makes me smile bright :")

Answer (score 1):

According to Quran it can happen. 
Check this out (36/57) :

> **They shall have fruits and all that they call for.**

In the Afterlife, as you may know there won't be any matter but only God's light (heaven) and it's absence (hell) (24/35):

> **Allah is the Lighter of the heavens and the earth. The example of His Light is like a tube, in which there is a wick. The wick is in a lamp and the lamp is as a glittering planet kindled from a Blessed Tree, an olive that is neither of the East nor of the West. Its oil would almost shine forth though no fire touched it. Light upon light; Allah guides to His Light whom He will. Allah strikes parables for people. Allah has knowledge of all things**

and that light will take form of whatever you desire.

Keep in mind that getting to Jannah is the easy part, but being in which place of it is the hardest.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, Allah (SWT) says that when you get to Jannah, Insha'Allah, you will not regret anything from this dunya. Therefore, you will not want to relive this life.